# Controlar cuando un pdf tienes mas de una pagina

Tags: php, html, html5, pdf, dompdf

el siguiente código me crea y exporta al sistema un PDF con una factura, el problema radica en que cuando tengo mas de una página debería hacerme saltar a la siguiente pagina, sin embargo lo que me provoca es un colapso entre la segunda tabla y mi ultima tabla con los dos cuadros. ¿Podrían echarme una mano?

```html
<?php
require_once('../../lib/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
include_once '../../lib/own/php/loadAllPhp.php';

setlocale(LC_TIME,"es_ES.UTF-8");

if(isset($_POST["factura"])){

    $factura = Doctrine_core::getTable('Facturas')->find($_POST['id']);
    $lineas=Doctrine_Query::create()->from('LineaFactura')->where('idFactura = ?',$factura->id)->orderBy('id')->execute();
    $IVA = str_pad(number_format(($factura->IVA * $factura->baseImponible) / 100,2),2, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);

    $tipo = "FACTURA";
    $num = $factura->factura_num;
 $metodosDePago = Doctrine_Core::getTable('MetodosDePago')->find($factura->metodo_pago);

}elseif(isset($_POST["albaran"])){

    $factura = Doctrine_core::getTable('Albaranes')->find($_POST['id']);
    $lineas=Doctrine_Query::create()->from('LineaAlbaran')->where('idAlbaran = ?',$factura->id)->orderBy('id')->execute();
    $IVA = str_pad(number_format(($factura->IVA * $factura->baseImponible) / 100,2),2, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);

    $tipo = "ALBARAN";
    $num = $factura->albaran_num;

    $metodosDePago = Doctrine_Core::getTable('MetodosDePago')->find($factura->metodoPago);

}elseif(isset($_POST["presupuesto"])){

    $factura = Doctrine_core::getTable('Presupuestos')->find($_POST['id']);
    $lineas=Doctrine_Query::create()->from('LineaPresupuesto')->where('idPresupuesto = ?',$factura->id)->orderBy('id')->execute();
    $IVA = str_pad(number_format(($factura->IVA * $factura->baseImponible) / 100,2),2, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);

    $tipo = "PRESUPUESTO";
    $num = $factura->presupuesto_num;

    $metodosDePago = Doctrine_Core::getTable('MetodosDePago')->find($factura->metodoPago);
}

$clientes=Doctrine_Core::getTable('Clientes')->find($factura->idCliente);
$margen = 17;
$codigo = "
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>" . $tipo . "</title>
            <style>
            .parent {
                padding: 10px;
                color: black;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                clear:both;
            }
            .parent-table {
                padding-top: 20px;
                color: #0A416B;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                clear:both;
            }
            .right h4 {
                text-align:left !important;
                margin-left: 5px !important;
                margin-top: 2px !important;
            }
            .left, .center, .right {
                float:left;
                width:32%;
                border: 1px solid #5883B0;
                margin-right: 20px;
                text-align: center;
                background:#dfedf4;

            }
            .left h4, .center h4{
                border-bottom: 1px solid #5883B0;
                background:#dfedf4;
                margin-top: 0px;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .right p {
                text-align:left;
            }
            .left p, .center p, .right p {
                font-size:14px;
                padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
                margin-top: -5px;

            }
            table tr td, table tr th {
                text-align: left;
                color:black;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body style='padding: 20px;'>
            <div style='width: 100%; position: relative; '>
                <div style='width: 75%; float: left;'>
                    <h2 style='border-bottom:3px solid #5883B0;'>LAS 3-J PUERTO REAL S.L.</h2>
                    <p> B-11466828<br>
                        Pol. Ind. El Portal, Conjunto Piscis, C/ Mauritania N&#176; 25<br>
                        11408 Jerez de la Frontera (Cádiz)<br>
                        Tfno: 956 14 28 38<br>
                        info@lucicolor.com<br>
                        www.lucicolor.com<br>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div style='width: 25%; float: right; margin-top: 20px;'>
                    <img style='width: 100%;' src='" . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/intranet/logo_factura.png'/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='parent'>
                <div class='left' style='width:20%;'>
                    <h4>" . $tipo . "</h4>
                    <p>N&#176;" . $num . "</p>
                </div>

                <div class='center' style='width:26%;'>
                    <h4>Fecha</h4>
                    <p>".strftime("%d de %B de %Y (%A)", strtotime($factura->fecha))."</p>
                </div>
                <div class='right' style='width:47.5%;'>
                    <h4>$clientes->codigo &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; $clientes->nombreFac</h4>
                    <p>
                        NIF/CIF $clientes->cifFac &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Tfno: $clientes->telefonoFac<br>
                        $clientes->direccionFac<br>
                        $clientes->codigoPostalFac &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; $clientes->ciudadFac<br>
                        $clientes->email
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>";
            if(isset($_POST["factura"])){
                if($factura->albaran != NULL /*|| $factura->numPedido != NULL*/){
                    $codigo.="
                        <div style='text-align:center;
                            border: 1px solid #5883B0;
                            width:18%;
                            clear:left;
                            position:relative;
                            top:-25px;
                            background:#dfedf4;
                            border-radius:10px !important;
                            margin-right:20px;
                            padding-top:-10px;
                            padding-bottom:-10px;'>

                            <p style='font-size:14px; margin-left:10px; text-align:left'>";
                            $albaran_realnum = Doctrine_core::getTable('Albaranes')->find($factura->albaran);
                            //if($factura->albaran != NULL){
                                $codigo.="<strong>Alb&#225ran N&#186:</strong>$albaran_realnum->albaran_num<br>";
                            //}
                            /*if($factura->numPedido != NULL){
                                $codigo.="<strong>Pedido N&#186:</strong> $factura->numPedido<br>";
                            }*/
                         //$tieneAlbaran=5;
                    $codigo.="
                            </p>
                        </div>";
                }
            }
            $codigo .= "
            <div class='parent-table'>
                <table style='border-collapse: collapse;font-size:11; border:2px solid #5883B0; width: 100%;' cellpadding=0;'>
                    <tr style='background:#dfedf4;border-bottom:1px solid #5883B0;'>
                        <th style=' border-bottom:2px solid #5883B0'>C&oacute;digo</th>
                        <th style='padding:3px; border-bottom:2px solid #5883B0' align='left'>Descripci&oacute;n</th>
                        <th style='padding:3px; border-bottom:2px solid #5883B0'>Cant</th>
                        <th style='padding:3px; border-bottom:2px solid #5883B0'>Precio</th>
                        <th style='padding:3px; border-bottom:2px solid #5883B0'>Dto</th>
                        <th style='padding:3px; border-bottom:2px solid #5883B0'>Precio Unitario Dto. %</th>
                        <th style='padding:3px; border-bottom:2px solid #5883B0'>Importe</th>
                    </tr>";
                $contadorFilas = 0;
                foreach($lineas as $linea){
                    $contadorFilas++;
                    $margen = $margen - 1;
                    $articulo = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Articulos')->find($linea->idArticulo);
                    $precioUnitarioDescuento = str_pad(number_format($articulo->precio - ($articulo->precio * $linea->descuento / 100),2),2, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
                    $importeTotal = str_pad(number_format($precioUnitarioDescuento * $linea->unidad,2),2, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
                    $codigo.="
                    <tr>
                        <td style='border-right:2px solid #5883B0;border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;' align='center !important;'>$articulo->codigo</td>
                        <td style='border-right:2px solid #5883B0;border-bottom:2px solid #ccc; font-size:13px; '>$articulo->nombre</td>
                        <td style='border-right:2px solid #5883B0;border-bottom:2px solid #ccc; ' align='center !important'>$linea->unidad</td>
                        <td style='border-right:2px solid #5883B0;border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;' align='center !important'>$articulo->precio</td>
                        <td style='border-right:2px solid #5883B0;border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;' align='center !important'>".number_format($linea->descuento,0)." %</td>
                        <td style='border-right:2px solid #5883B0;border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;' align='center !important'>$precioUnitarioDescuento</td>
                        <td style='border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;' align='right !important'>$importeTotal</td>
                    </tr>";

                };

                $codigo.="
                    <tr>
                        <td width=6%; style='border-right:1px solid #5883B0;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width=28%; style='border-right:1px solid #5883B0;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width=6%; style='border-right:1px solid #5883B0;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width=6%; style='border-right:1px solid #5883B0;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width=6%; style='border-right:1px solid #5883B0;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width=6%; style='border-right:1px solid #5883B0;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width=6%;style='border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;'>"; for($i = 1; $i < $margen; $i++){
                            $codigo.= "<br>";  /*Saltos de linea para crear una tabla que llegue hasta el final de una pagina*/
                        };$codigo.="</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='color:blue; font-size:13px;' colspan='7'>
                            $factura->pie<br><br>
                            En virtud de Ley de Protección de Datos Personales, le informamos que sus datos personales son confidenciales y que forman parte de un fichero de Gestión con la finalidad de gestionar la relación contractual, y remitirle información comercial, inclusive por medios electrónicos. Puede ejercer sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, cancelación y oposición dirigiéndose a Las 3-J Puerto Real S.L., Pol. Ind. El Portal, C/Mauritania Nº 25, 11408 Jerez de la Frontera (Cádiz), adjuntando una copia de su DNI o CIF.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style='border-collapse:collapse;position:fixed;top:895px;left:20px;margin-top:15px;width:70%;background:#dfedf4;border:2px solid #5883B0;font-size:15px;'>
                    <tr>
                        <th style='padding:3px;border:2px solid #5883B0;'>Otros Datos</th>
                        <th style='padding:3px;border:2px solid #5883B0;'>Base imponible</th>";
                        if($factura->descuento > 0){
                            $codigo.="<th style='padding:3px;border:2px solid #5883B0;'>Otro Dto.</th>";
                        }
                    $codigo.="
                        <th style='padding:3px;border:2px solid #5883B0;'>IVA</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style='background:#dfedf4;  '>
                        <td style='border:1px solid #5883B0;' rowspan='2'>";
                        if($factura->numPedido){
                            $codigo.="<strong>Nº de Pedido: </strong>".$factura->numPedido."<br>";

                        }
                        $codigo.="Forma Pago: $clientes->metodoPago<br>";
                        /*if(isset($metodosDePago)){
                            $codigo.="Forma Pago: $metodosDePago->nombre<br>";*/

                            if($clientes->metodoPago == "Transferencia bancaria"){
                                $codigo.="N&#176; cuenta: ES59 2100 7438 1723 0013 5236 La Caixa<br>";
                            }

                            $codigo.="Vencimiento:$factura->vencimiento";
                        //}

                        $codigo.="</td>
                        <td align='right !important' style='border:2px solid #5883B0;'>$factura->baseImponible</td>";
                        if($factura->descuento > 0){
                            $codigo.="<td align='right !important' style='border:2px solid #5883B0;'>".$factura->descuento." %</td>";
                        }
                        $codigo.="<td align='right !important' style='border:2px solid #5883B0;'>".number_format($factura->IVA,0)." %</td>";
                    $codigo.="
                    </tr>
                    <tr style='background:#dfedf4;  '>
                        <td align='right !important' style='border:2px solid #5883B0;'><strong>$factura->baseImponible</strong></td>";
                        if($factura->descuento > 0){
                            $precioDto = (($factura->subTotal + ($factura->subTotal * 21 / 100)) - $factura->total)*(-1);
                            $codigo.="<td align='right !important' style='border:2px solid #5883B0;'><strong>".number_format($precioDto,2)." &#8364;</strong></td>";
                        }
                    $codigo.="
                        <td align='right !important'style='border:2px solid #5883B0;'>+ <strong>$IVA</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table style='margin-top:15px;position:fixed;top:895px;left:565px;width:140px;padding-left:8px;background:#dfedf4;font-size:1.2em;border:2px solid #5883B0;'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>TOTAL</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='center' style='padding-left:40px !important;'><strong>$factura->total</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
";




$codigo=utf8_decode($codigo);
/*var_dump($codigo);
die;*/
$dompdf=new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($codigo);
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
$dompdf->render();

$nombrec=str_replace(".", "", $clientes->nombre);
$facturac=str_replace(".", "", $factura->fecha);

//$dompdf->stream($tipo." - ".$nombrec."-".$facturac.".pdf");

$dompdf->stream("mipdf.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando yo generaba dinámicamente facturas en pdf con una clase php, lo que hacía era controlar el número de líneas que caben dentro del espacio que yo tengo delimitado, luego cada vez que imprimo una línea, controlo si sigue dentro del rango, y si se pasa, genero una nueva página con sus cabeceras, etc... y sigo imprimiendo con el iterador que corresponda

Comment: Es decir, debería usar una condición para controlar el número de filas que caben en una página completa y si sobrepasa ese número o contador pues crear una nueva página y comenzar de nuevo a iterar, he entendido eso, pero me surge una nueva duda al respecto, esta condición de controlar las lineas debe ir antes de empezar a crear las lineas o dentro de mi bucle.

Comment: Creo que deberías separar un poco las cosas. Algo como esto:1- Función para crear las cabeceras necesarias, tipo de documento, titulos, logo de empresa etc...2- Función de cierre de documento, los típicos total, subtotal, iva etc. 3- Bucle de las líneas que componen la factura 3A- Si las lineas superan las permitidas, lanzas función de cierre de documento y luego otra vez la de cabeceras – Vera Canet hace 4 min    editar

Comment: vale muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha sido de ayuda